# Are right-angled Artin groups always CAT(0)?

Tags: geometric-group-theory

To each right-angled Artin group $A_\Gamma$ there is an associated space $S_\Gamma$ on which the group acts on (the Salvetti complex). The fundamental group of the Salvetti complex is the right-angled Artin group itself $\pi_1(S_\Gamma)=A_\Gamma$.

Is $A_\Gamma$ always a CAT(0) group? Is this because the universal cover of $S_\Gamma$ is simply connected?

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence, because universal covers are always simply connected...

Comment: @user1729 yes that is clear. my confusion was if acting on the universal cover is sufficient. but it has been answered.

Comment: Again, a group $G$ always acts (freely) on the universal cover of a (connected) space $S$ if $\pi_1(S)\cong G$ (which is the case here). The part you have to prove here is that $S_{\Gamma}$ is a non-positively curved cube complex. Everything else follows from theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite graph. Then the associated Salvetti complex $S_{\Gamma}$ is naturally a finite cube complex. Furthermore, Gromov's condition on the link is easy to verify, so that $S_{\Gamma}$ is a non-positively curved cube complex. Finally, we deduce that the universal covering $\widetilde{S}_{\Gamma}$ is a CAT(0) cube complex on which the right-angled Artin group $A_{\Gamma}$ acts geometrically: $A_{\Gamma}$ is CAT(0).

If $\Gamma$ is an infinite graph, then $A_{\Gamma}$ is not finitely-generated and cannot be CAT(0).